# Set max & min height for line being drawn using onDraw

Tags: android, ondraw

I have a custom view in my project. In the view class I draw a line using onDraw method. The height of the line can be changed by swiping up and down.How can I set a max and min value for the height of that line?

This is my code

```
 package com.example.richyrony.draw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Richy & Rony on 26-01-2018.
 */

public class Line extends View {


    PointF topLeft = new PointF(100, 100);
    PointF topRight = new PointF(290, 100);
    PointF bottomLeft = new PointF(100, 290);
    PointF bottomRight = new PointF(290, 290);
    private final int NONE = -1, TOUCH_TOP_LEFT = 0, TOUCH_TOP_RIGHT = 1, TOUCH_BOT_LEFT = 2, TOUCH_BOT_RIGHT = 3;
    int currentTouch = NONE;

    Float lineTwoStartx = 250f;
    Float lineTwoStart = 50f;
    Float lineTwoEndx = 250f;
    Float lineTwoEnd = 200f;


    Float lineOneStartx = 50f;
    Float lineOneStart = 50f;
    ;
    Float lineOneEndx = 50f;
    Float lineOneEnd = 200f;

    RectF touchArea = new RectF(0, 0, 350, 350);
    Paint paint;

    public Line(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(lineOneStartx, lineOneStart, lineOneEndx, lineOneEnd, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(lineTwoStartx, lineTwoStart, lineTwoEndx, lineTwoEnd, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(lineOneEndx, lineOneEnd, lineTwoEndx, lineTwoEnd, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(lineOneStartx, lineOneStart, lineTwoStartx, lineTwoStart, paint);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            //The user just put their finger down.
            //We check to see which corner the user is touching
            //And set our global, currentTouch, to the appropriate constant.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (touchArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    currentTouch = TOUCH_TOP_LEFT;

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "tf" + currentTouch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }   else {
                    return false; //Return false if user touches none of the corners
                }
                return true; //Return true if the user touches one of the corners
            //Now we know which corner the user is touching.
            //When the user moves their finger, we update the point to the user position and invalidate.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                switch (currentTouch) {
                    case TOUCH_TOP_LEFT:
                        lineOneEnd = event.getY();
                        invalidate();
                        return true;

                }
                //We returned true for all of the above cases, because we used the event
                return false; //If currentTouch is none of the above cases, return false

            //Here the user lifts up their finger.
            //We update the points one last time, and set currentTouch to NONE.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                switch (currentTouch) {
                    case TOUCH_TOP_LEFT:
                        lineOneEnd = event.getY(); 
                        currentTouch = NONE;
                        invalidate();
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And also if anyone has any idea on how to measure angles between two lines it would be helpful

Comment: `"how to measure angles between two line in android studio"` - android studio is not designed to measure angles between two lines

Comment: Oh ok. That's unfortunate

Comment: however you can do that in java without any problems: see `Math#atan2` method and/or the whole `Math` class

Comment: Ok.Thanks.Will try

Comment: @Rnld to clarify what pskink tried to say:  Android Studio is just an IDE. You can't measure angles between two lines in Android Studio, but you can write code in Android Studio to do it on an Android device

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think I had the question out in the wrong way